Reading & Writing other process's STD handles in python
I am trying to use Pywin32 to get the STD handles of another process, then read and write to them.
My source code is:
import win32api
import win32con
import win32file

STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10  
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11
STD_ERROR_HANDLE = -12

pid = 4908

process_handle = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid)

stdin_handle = win32api.GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)
stdout_handle = win32api.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
stderr_handle = win32api.GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE)

win32file.WriteFile(stdout_handle, b"Hello from Python!")

win32api.CloseHandle(process_handle)

It raises this error: pywintypes.error: (6, 'WriteFile', 'The handle is invalid.'). How can i work around this?
Note: I got the STD handle constants from here.

There's no reason to call OpenProcess() when all you're doing with its return value is passing it to CloseHandle().

You can't get the STD handles of another existing process. You can only get the STD handles of the calling process (which is what you are doing) or redirect the STD handles of a new process you spawn with CreateProcess(). Otherwise, the only other thing you can do is AttachConsole() to the console of the target process ID and then write to your own STD output. But that is not the same thing as writing to another process' STD output. I think you need to explain your goal in more detail. Your current premise is not viable.
